# Image not found when opening in browser

Tags: html, css

I have come into an issue where my webpage will not load a background image in any browser if I open it directly into the browser, but if I open it up via a live server addon for VS code it works entirely fine and loads everything correctly. I have videos attatched to the webpage which load entirely fine in both scenarios, and have come to a bit of a deadend...

[file's to see if file pathing is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Iaq.png)

[Where the image should be loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p88v0.png)

[The html file calling the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrz4m.png)

Comment: Try writing your code in triple backticks instead of posting links of images

Comment: Check with browser console if you get a 404 error for the image

Comment: Like @Sfili_81 said, check the browser console. The easiest way to do that on a laptop or desktop is to right click anywhere in the page, then click "Inspect". Then look for the "Network" tab on the panel that appears.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess at the moment but it might be, on the second image that you posted, that you have detailed `../../` twice. This is telling the path to back up by two folders then look for the `assets` folder.

Looking at your file layout. You have an index page then an assets folder which contains a videos folder which contains the image.

You shouldn't need to back up out of the folders using any itteration of `../` from where you index page is located. The correct path might simply be `assets/videos/cover_image.jpg`